# How to customize installation with `cargo`?

Tags: rust, installation, customization, rust-cargo

Say I have a standard Cargo project

```
my-package
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── bin
    │   └── an_executable.rs
    └── lib.rs
```

For reasons related to its proper functioning, I need to install the executable `an_executable` as root and with the [setuid bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) turned on.
I can easily do this from the working directory with

```
cargo build --release
sudo install -o root -g root -m 4755 -t /usr/local/bin target/release/an_executable
```

Is there a way to configure the installation process (options in `Cargo.toml`, custom build script...) so that the same happens when I try to install it with `cargo install my-package`?

Comment: Go upvote this issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is beyond what `cargo` does.

As an alternative, you can control building the package using a standard `Makefile` and use an `install` target that does what you need. Something to the tune of [this](https://github.com/lukaslueg/macro_railroad_ext/blob/master/extension/Makefile).

Keep in mind that not all target platforms - Windows in particular - have a concept like `setuid`.

Comment: Yes using the Makefile is what I'm currently doing, but it works only from the package directory. I was hoping for a way to accomplish the same when installing from crates.io